# Reactjs error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: props.delete_button is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

so when i try to delete an article it's deleted, but the only issue that i have to refresh the page , so i updated the list that has the articles, however it works but without updateing the page,and just diplays that error ' Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: props.delete_button is not a function.'. I assume that the issue is in the delete_button function.

```
import React from 'react'
import APIService from '../APIService'

function ArticleList(props) {

let edit_button = (article) =>{
  props.edit_button(article)
}

let delete_button = (article) => {
  APIService.delete_Article(article.id)
  .then( () => Array.from(props.delete_button(article)))
  .catch(console.log(Error))
}
 
  return (
    <div>
        {props.articles && props.articles.length && props.articles.map(article => {
                return (
                <div key={article.id}>
                <h2> {article.title} </h2>
                <p> {article.description} </p>

                  <div className='row'>
                  <div className='col-md-1'>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={ () => edit_button(article)}>Update</button>
                  </div>
                  <div className='col'>
                    <button onClick={() => delete_button(article)} className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>

                  </div>
                  </div>

                <hr className='hr_class'/>
                </div>
            )})}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ArticleList
```

Comment: Could you add the `delete_button` code you pass down with the props?

Comment: now the error changed to ``` Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.from (<anonymous>) ```